# Increase processing time in Unity with captureDeltaTime

Tags: unity-game-engine, time, simulation, ros

I'm currently trying to implement a robotics simulation in Unity. Lidar data will be published to ROS and camera data will be stored using the perception package. Unfortunately, although I have pretty decent hardware (RTX4090, Intel i7-13700F, 64 GB RAM), frame rate drops to around 15 fps mainly because of the perception camera. Also, stuttering can be seen in the data. I read about coupling game time to frame calculation by using "captureDeltaTime", which would result in a gap between real time and game time. That wouldn't be problem for me as long as the data is time consistent.
Is this a possible solution to create time consistent data?
And how would it be implemented? Can I simply create a script with
`Time.captureDeltaTime = 2.0f` in the start() method or is that too simple a thought?

So far, I tried publishing sim-time to ROS. Unfortunately, the stuttering was still present.

Comment: Yes you can simply set [`Time.captureDeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-captureDeltaTime.html) .. probably not to `2f` though as this would basically mean one frame should take 2 seconds ;)

Comment: If you're not too concerned with capture rate try `fixedDeltaTime` / `FixedUpdate` instead: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html, https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html. These are frame rate independant - they vary with hardware but are consistent metronomes on each device. See also https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TimeFrameManagement.html.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to create a separate game object just holding the script with 'time.captureDeltaTime' in the setup part. I would have assumed, that frame rate drops with respect to the given value but is constant in return. Unfortunately, frame rate doesn't change at all. I still get the variable frame rate dropping from 15 to 8 fps from time to time and creating that stuttering effect. Does the value have to be set at a specific location or does it have a "global effect"?

Comment: If I adjust the fixedDeltaTime, this only affects the physics updates, right? I need to "slow down" the computation of the whole simulation. Or did I understand the concept wrong?